# Search for pagination entries

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web, spring-data-jpa

Help please, I'm trying to make a search so that it also saves the pagination parameters of the records, but nothing happens, because the search value is transferred to the server in input and saved somewhere and then reused not received.

If it turned out somewhere to temporarily save the search parameter from input and then substitute it, but I could not find a similar solution without using javascript.

How to use search records with pagination?

Code Form:

```
<form action="/admin/users" method="get" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input type="search" name="search" value="${search?ifExists}"
                   placeholder="Enter name for search" aria-label="Search" class="form-control">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm my-0 p" type="submit">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </button>

        </form>
```

Code Request:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public String viewAdminUsers(
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "10") Integer size,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "id") String sort,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "ASC") String dir,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String search,
        Model model) {
    Page<User> users = userService.userList(page, size, sort, dir, search);
    model.addAttribute("url", "/admin/users");
    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    model.addAttribute("sort", sort);
    model.addAttribute("dir", dir);
    model.addAttribute("search", search);
    model.addAttribute("roles", Role.values());
    return "adminUsers";
}
```

Post page method:

```
public Page<User> userList(Integer pageNo, Integer pageSize, String sortBy, String directionBy, String search) {
    Pageable paging;
    if (directionBy.equals("DESC")) {
        paging = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize, Sort.by(sortBy).descending());
    } else {
        paging = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize, Sort.by(sortBy).ascending());
    }
    if (search != null && !search.isEmpty()) {
        return userRepo.findByFullnameContains(search, paging);
    } else {
        return userRepo.findAll(paging);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try checking PagingAndSortingRepository? That provides inbuild functionality for pagination and sorting. Doc Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html

Comment: Everything in it is the same as what I did, I need to do so that when searching for the parameters, the exposed paginations are saved